# How can I initialize Process proc without running exec on my Runtime rt?

Tags: java

My IDE is complaining that it doesn't know if proc was initialized:

```
Process proc
```

It's complaining because the initialization of proc is happening inside try scope:

```
// Runtime Getter
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        BufferedReader stdInput;
        BufferedReader stdError;

        // Get output for this executable
        String[] commands = {"system.exe","-get t"};
        Process proc;
        try{
            proc = rt.exec(commands);
            stdInput=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    proc.getInputStream()));
            stdError=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    proc.getErrorStream()));

        }catch(IOException e){}
```

Isn't it bad to put everything that's complaining inside a try block? Is there another nicer way?

Comment: Initialize `proc` to be null outside the try, then check to see if it's null inside the catch.

Comment: Not directly to your question, but I would prefer [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: Don't ignore exceptions! Either don't catch them and declare them on your method, or return, or throw another exception (possibly your own subclass of RuntimeException). Anything but ignoring it! That's what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick hack is to set it to null when you declare it.

However, you should minimize the scope of your variables, and assuming that `proc` is not used outside of that try-catch block, it should be declared and assigned at the same time.

If it is used outside of the block, then you'll have to handle the case that it would be null after the try-catch -- just ignoring the `IOException` is not a good idea.